# Lambda Expression in c++ std::copy_if

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr

Can somebody explain or help me why this isnt working?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Publication> > Bibliography::givePubWithIFHigherThan(float value) const
  {
  Publication *p;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Publication>> highIFPubs(publications);
  auto checkIF = std::mem_fun(p->IFHigherThan(value));
  auto last = std::copy_if(publications.begin(), publications.end, highIFPubs.begin(),
                           [=] (std::shared_ptr<Publication> p)
                            {
                            return checkIF(*p, value);
                            });
  return highIFPubs;

  }



class Publication
  {
  public:
    Publication(std::string aTitle, int aYear, std::string anID);
    virtual bool IFHigherThan(float value) const {return false;};

  private:

  };


class Paper : public Publication
  {
  public:
    Paper(std::string aTitle, int aYear, std::string aJournal, float aImpactFactor);
    bool IFHigherThan(float value) const {return value < impactFactor;};


  private:


  };
```

At the moment i get this error,

```
 no matching function for call to 'mem_fun(bool)'
   auto checkIF = std::mem_fun(p->IFHigherThan(value));
                                                     ^
```

Comment: It's because you are *calling* the `IFHigherThan` function, not passing a pointer to it.

Comment: But p is a pointer right?

Comment: Yes, `p` is a pointer, but `p->IFHigherThan(value)` is a function call which results in a `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::mem_fun` is a depracated helper function that will probably be [soon removed from the standard library.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm) `std::mem_fn` would be a better choice.

Moreover, if you want to use `std::mem_fn`, `std::mem_fun` or `std::bind` with a function, then you pass in a *pointer to function*, not a call expression, so instead of:

```
auto checkIF = std::mem_fun(p->IFHigherThan(value));
```

use:

```
auto checkIF = std::mem_fn(&Publication::IFHigherThan);
```

Alternatively, don't use any wrapper, just directly call the selected member function:

```
auto last = std::copy_if(publications.begin(), publications.end(), highIFPubs.begin(),
                       [=] (std::shared_ptr<Publication> p)
                        {
                        return p->IFHigherThan(value);
                        });
```

There is one more logical error you have in your code:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Publication>> highIFPubs(publications.size());
```

should be:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Publication>> highIFPubs;
```

and then instead of:

```
auto last = std::copy_if(publications.begin(), publications.end()
                       , highIFPubs.begin(),
                    //   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

you should be using `std::back_inserter`:

```
auto last = std::copy_if(publications.begin(), publications.end()
                       , std::back_inserter(highIFPubs),
                    //   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

as you don't actually know how many elements will the resultant vector have.

Comment: Thanks, still have a mistake in my copy_if function. Is there a problem to use lambda this way?

Comment: Still have the same error.

 no matching function for call to 'copy_if(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Publication> >::const_iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Publication> >::iterator, Bibliography::givePubWithIFHigherThan(float) const::__lambda0)'
                             });
                              ^

Comment: @user4390280 because you have a typo: `.end` instead of `.end()`